# Maximizing expectation (probability stuff)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expectation

A wheel-of-fortune has the numbers from 1 to 2n arranged in a circle. The wheel has a spinner, and
a spin randomly determines the two numbers at the opposite ends of the spinner. How would you
arrange the numbers on the wheel to maximize the expected value of the sum of the numbers chosen?
What is this maximum?

Comment: What makes you think rearrangement affects the expected value?

Comment: Many assumptions are needed to be made to be able to attack this question. In what position does the wheel start? How fast does the game master spin? Is the slowing-down of the wheel when passing each new needle the same or can it vary with different needles (positions of the wheel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expectation is fixed no matter how you arrange the numbers.

Given any arrangement, there are $2n$ possible output pairs, each with probability $\frac{1}{2n}$. For convenience, let these $2n$ pairs be $(a_1, b_1)$, $(a_2, b_2)$, $\cdots$, $(a_{2n}, b_{2n})$. Then the expected output is
$$
\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{i=1}^{2n}(a_i + b_i)
$$
Note that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}(a_i + b_i)$ is double the sum of all $2n$ numbers, which is fixed.

Comment: Actually, there are $2n$ possible output pairs. This does not affect the reasoning, that the mean is the same for every arrangement.

Comment: @Did Thanks. Fixed.